# Cannot start VSCode anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code, icu

My VSCode is not starting anymore neither as a user nor an administrator. Found a debug.log file in the  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code" directory, which contains following line:
[0829/061645.007:ERROR:icu_util.cc(252)] Couldn't mmap icu data file

No idea what this means nor what the problem shall be.
Any help/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue too. Your VS code has probably been damaged. It will be worthwhile if you reinstall it. I found a couple of links for you to help. [Click this link discussing about Microsoft Edge failure and ICU file](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-wont-open/57309a7d-8fa4-450a-85c2-c6287a228ade) to see the discussion on the same but on the Microsoft forum.
The next thing I can say is that the ICU file which is mentioned is within the installation folder of VS code. You should make sure that the installation folder is on the local disk or try excluding it from the Anti Virus.

Comment: Reinstalling helped. Will have to observe Anti Virus behaviour... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it.